What early 60s puppet show similar to fireball XL5 used the phrase "Meson Power?"
The spacecraft looked like a toy gyroscope. I think it had a cylinder that stuck up out of the top when it wanted to go use "Meson Power."
I think I remember it being at the bottom of an aquarium, but I may be confusing it with Diver Dan.

This must surely be Space Patrol, a puppet show written and produced by Roberta Leigh, and originally broadcast in 1963. She had previously worked with Gerry Anderson on puppet shows like The Adventures of Twizzle and Torchy the Battery Boy, which accounts for the similarity in look between Space Patrol and Anderson's works - for example, Fireball XL5.
From the wikipedia summary:

The series is set in the year 2100, by which time the indigenous and
autonomous civilizations on Earth, Mars and Venus have banded together
to form the United Galactic Organization (UGO). Space Patrol is the
UGO's military wing, and the series follows the actions of this
interplanetary force, focusing on the missions of a tiny unit led by
the heroic, bearded Captain Larry Dart...
The Galasphere [their spaceship] had a top speed of about 800,000 mph,
using "meson power"

The spaceship indeed looked rather like a toy gyroscope.


Bit of an overreeach to call themselves "galactic" organization because they occupy three planets in one solar system.

@DJClayworth "The term "galaxy" was used inaccurately, but consistently, to refer to a solar system in the series, so "Galactic Control" only supervised the local planets and "other galaxies" referred to nearby star-systems."

I looked it up on Wikipedia, and "Joseph" is indeed apparently J. Michael Straczynski's first name, though this is the one and only time I've seen him called "Joe."   I imagine the designer of this cover art also looked it up on the internet, because they'd never heard of him and assumed that whoever wrote the specifications was being lazy.
